# Django - How to use my custom filters inside any included template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters, django-filters

I can't make use of my filters on my included child view, the filter works when is written directly, but I need the child view as inclusion...

Here is the filter:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def lower(value):
    return value.lower()
```

Here is how I call my template:

```
{% load app_filters %}
{% include 'view.template.html' %}
```

***view.template.html***

```
<h1>{{ 'HELLO WORLD!' | lower }}</h1>
```

But the thing is that it doesn't work been included, unless I had to add the ***{% load app_filters %}*** inside ***view.template.html*** but I need this template for my angular app too, so I can't write this line in the template. *It is a shared template for my angular app and separated view for no-angular template in Django.*

How could I inject my custom filters to the included view without modifying the view? It is possible to pass as `{% include 'view.template.html' with app_filters=app_filters %}?` It is only the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving at the moment with:

```
<div ng-hide="true">
    {% load app_filters %}
</div>
```

In ***view.template.html***, so it won't affect the template in angular, and lets load the django's filters as expected to be.